# How to block a port connection (Ex: GMAIL) for incoming mails and allow only for outgoing mails?

Tags: iptables, email, http, https

Is there a way to block connections for incoming requests for GMAIL at port level? Is it that all protocols use same port for incoming and outgoing connections?

Comment: Please edit the question and define which email daemon are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block incoming ports 25, 465 and 587. And you will have only outgoing mail from this server. Also you can consider to set the SMTP daemon to listen only to 127.0.0.1 which will make it accept incoming mail only via localhost and send mail to the world

Comment: Thanks for the response... By doing so, can I restrict my Linux system from sending outgoing gmail?

Comment: @ShreeVidhya, in your question you mention not to receive mail from google and send everywhere. If you want not to send to google you can check in your particular mail server configuration to blacklist google

Comment: thanks Romeo Ninov... I would like to block the connections at port level...

Comment: So make combination of port and IP (get all MX records for domain gmail.com, googlemail.com and so on)